# Wireline internet (cable, dsl) availability data source

Tags: data, united-states, utility-network

I'm looking for data on spatial availability of cable, dsl, etc. internet service in Washington State, USA.  Mainly interested in the big telco providers Comcast, ATT, etc.

Comment: Contact the owners of the cables but don't be surprised if they don't want to share their data... A person, so inclined, could put a great deal of the United States into chaos with that information and an axe - It happened in Sydney (Australia) in the late 80's and took days to fix (No EFTPOS for nearly a working week). Are you after the cable locations or the serviced area?

Comment: I'm after the service area, not the cable locations.  I'm in contact with BroadbandNow.com, a service that has been aggregating internet service availability by zip code, I'll see if they're interested in sharing their data.

Comment: Fair enough. They never caught the guy in Sydney but they recon he was a recently redundant Telstra cable guy - he knew *exactly* which ones to cut... Service (coverage) area should be (freely) available from the individual telcos then it is just a data exercise compiling them (i.e. some will give a PDF, others a CSV, shapefiles, TAB files, online maps etc..) but not too difficult.